# Detail view from core data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, segue

I saw a question like this the other day and I was hoping it would be answered but it seems to of been deleted now. Im not sure why.

What I have been following is [Ray Wenderlich's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller) tutorial on importing data into core data on launch and populating a table with it. His tutorials are excellent but he does not then explain how to provide a detail view for the application. The final tutorial ends on this:

[image]

I am lost about how to create the detail view using core data. I have done so using an array but I cannot seem to incorporate it into this situation.

Has anyone done this tutorial before? Can I get directions into what method I should be looking at?

I have completed a detail view before using an array shown in [AppCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/). Would this work with core data?

I have been looking at this for a few days and it is breaking me down. I have done similar applications before but never with core data and I am a bit confused about passing the Data Between View Controllers.

Any suggestions or directions about where I should be looking?

Comment: I see more and more references to Ray's tutorials in questions about iOS basics. I'm starting to think that their step-by-step copy friendly format is becoming a crutch for beginning developers who then miss out on conceptual ideas such as passing a managed object context up a stack of view controllers.

Comment: @Abizern constructive comment thank you. I am trying to learn.

Comment: It's all in [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305). Not so much hand-holding, but you'll learn a lot more

Comment: Or if you want to see how to pass data between master-detail views [Your Second iOS App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/NextSteps/NextSteps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH8-SW1)

Comment: would this method work with a master-detail view and a normal uitableview? http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

Comment: Very clearly it does.

Comment: thank you for the suggestions. I am looking at them now though I do not appreciate your sarcasm. It benefits no one.

Comment: Dude. Ask a serious question and I'll help. Ask a question that I'm interested in and I'll even write a sample project. I'f I'm in a good mood I'll write a test app. I've given you two links and I read your question carefully enough to know that the the tutorial you mention in your comment is the same as you mention in the question. I'm not making fun of you, I'm, perhaps a bit too harshly, trying to get you to think a bit for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new UIViewController to act as your detail view controller. Give it a constructor so that you can pass in the data you want to use to customize it. [This tutorial](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2011/05/18/tutorial-using-uitableview-adding-a-detail-view-in-xcode-4/) describes how to create a generic detail view controller, you'd just need to expand it to customize the init method so you can pass in your data, and then use the data within the detail view to populate any relevant fields.